# Silverlight InstallStateChanged does not fire

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, installation, silverlight-oob

I'm developing an out-of-browser (OOB) app using Silverlight 4. For installation, I present a webpage with an install button to install the app OOB. When the user clicks the button, *Application.Current.Install* is executed, installing the app asynchronously.

Problem is, after the install process is complete, the *InstallStateChanged* event should fire, where I have code which copies data from my XAP file to the Isolated Storage. But the *InstallStateChanged* never fires, even though the main page displays properly upon installation.

I've tried this in Elevated Trust setting as well, no luck.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you show the code where you hook up to InstallStateChanged?  Especially *when* you do it?

Comment: There's really nothing to show. On my install page, I execute Application.Current.Install in the code behind. Then in the App code behind, I have an InstallStateChange event with code in it. When you refer to "hook up", are you suggesting I need to explicitly set a new event handler for InstallStateChanged to work? I'm doing this in VB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. I blame the lack of VB examples on the web for this :-)

In the Install_click event (executed by a user click event on the install button), I was failing to wire up the *InstallStateChanged* event, like so:

```
AddHandler Application.Current.InstallStateChanged, AddressOf App_InstallStateChanged
```

I failed to realize this step was needed and assumed the event fired on its own. Now I could proceed to put my post-install action code in the *App_InstallStateChanged* event routine:

```
Private Sub App_InstallStateChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  'Post-install execution code here
   Select Case Application.Current.InstallState
        Case InstallState.Installed
            DisplayInstalled() 'Routine that executes upon successful install
        Case InstallState.InstallFailed
            DisplayFailed()    'Routine that executes upon failed install
   End Select
End Sub
```